# How to avoid concurrency error for multiple files loading into a single table in ODI 12c

Tags: parallel-processing, bulk-load, oracle-data-integrator

I have a scenario where there are 3 files of 5 million lines each with 3 weeks of data is bulk mapped to a staging table. They run parallelly. If the data transfer for a file fails with a concurrency error, what will be the best way to load the data of the 3 files effectively into the stage table.
(I was asked this in an interview.)

Answer (score 0):

In ODI 12c, Parallel Target Table Load can be achieved by selecting the **Use Unique Temporary Object Names** checkbox in the Physical tab of a mapping. The work tables for each concurrent session will have a unique name.

I discuss it in more details in the Parallel Target Table Load section of this [blog on ODI 12c new features](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2013/11/oracle-data-integrator-12c-release-part-2/)

Comment: The parallel table load was a good read. Thanks for the response @JeromeFr